# Wrong position of items after using a customAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

This is the tutorial I have used: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/08/filter-custom-listviewbaseadapter.html

and I implemented to it an `onItemClickListener`

```
    OnItemClickListener myListViewClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String member_name = countrylist.get(position).getName();
            // get Internet status
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            if (isInternetPresent) {
                if (member_name.equals("aa")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Listview.this, Start.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    displayInterstitial();
            } else {
                prName.show();
            }
        }
    };
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(myListViewClicked);


}
```

so, let us suppose my original list is

```
Aa
BB
Ca
DD
```

and I type 'a' in the filter, then the list becomes

```
Aa
Ca
```

But when I click Ca, I get redirected into BB using further action that depends on .equal for each list item.

My code for my list and custom adapter is the same as in the tutrial, but the onclickitem listener, i have implemeneted it, so I think im missing something in it. I tried searching and found couple of same quesiton, but none answered, each with self-answer that was different than mine and i couldn't apply it to my cusotm adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is mostly because your are accessing the dataset directly.

```
 String member_name = countrylist.get(position).getName();
```

During the filtering you are probably instantiating and new `Collection` overriding the the reference you are using in your `Activity`.

Use

```
String member_name = ((Country)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getName();
```

and it will work.

`parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` accesses the underlying dataset in your `Adapter`, if your `getItem` is correctly implemented

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work unfortunetly, because .getName doesn't apply to it. I tried this as I have seen it in another answer, but it doesn't work :"(. "Can't resolve method 'getName'"

Comment: `((Country)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getName()`

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly .. Can you tell me what have u done?

Comment: `getItemAtPosition`, returns a generic `Object`.  Using `((Country)parent.getItemAtPosition(position))` you are casting the generic object to `Country`

Answer (score 1):

> You can use

```
String memberName=(YourObject)parent.getAdapter().get(postion).getName;
```

its easy.